# Definite Integral of $e^{\large x^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I know there's no elementary antiderivative of $e^{\large x^2}$.

But what if there's a definite integral like

$$\int_0^1e^{\large x^2}\ dx\ ?$$

I tried using basic definite integral property like $\displaystyle\int^a_0f(x)\ dx =\int^a_0f(a-x)\ dx $ but I could see no way out.

Comment: from Mathematica $\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi } \text{erfi}(1)$
can be expressed interm of error function

Comment: See [Gaussian integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using Maclaurin series of [exponential function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions), we will obtain
$$
e^{\large x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{\large 2n}}{n!}.
$$
Hence
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{x=0}^1\ e^{\large x^2}\ dx&=\int_{x=0}^1\ \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{\large 2n}}{n!}\ dx\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_{x=0}^1\ \frac{x^{\large 2n}}{n!}\ dx\\
&=\left.\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{\large 2n+1}}{(2n+1)\ n!}\right|_{x=0}^1\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n+1)\ n!}\\
&\approx 1.4626517459.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: FYI, the summation will yield accuracy $10^{-6}$ for $n=7$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: check how the improper integration of $\int{e^{-x^2}}$ happens, and use an $x\rightarrow{ix}$ mapping.